# Cocoa: Delaying one method call until a subsequent call is processed

Tags: multithreading, cocoa, event-handling

I've found myself in the following situation: I've got an `NSTableView` subclass with an active cell. when I click elsewhere on the user interface, the delegate method (i) is fired, this in turn fires (ii) (my own method) cocoa then proceeds to process the click, resulting in the final two calls. I was surprised and disappointed by this sequence, since I had assumed the mouse click would be the first rather than the last event processed. It also causes me a problem because the ideal implementation of `manageState` is dependent on some of the processing I do in `mouseDown:`, but of course when `manageState` is called `mouseDown:` has not yet been executed.

Is their a way to delay the execution of `manageState` until `mouseDown` has returned? For example, in `manageState` I'd say something like *Stop! a mouse down event might be in the events queue. Wait until it's finished, then resume*. As the previous sentence implies, it's also possible that this method could be triggered by something other than a mouse down. In this situation, there's no need to look out for a mouse down event and processing can continue as normal.

```
MOUSE CLICK on NSTextView while NSTableView cell has focus...

+-------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|Event                    |Triggered because                                       |
+=========================+========================================================+
|controlTextDidEndEditing:|The mouse click ends the editing session                |
|                         |of the active cell in my table view                     |
+-------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|manageState              |This method is a selector that belongs to a notification|
|                         |that is fired from within controlTextDidEndEditing:     |
+-------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|becomeFirstResponder     |I clicked on the NSTextView instance                    |
+-------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|mouseDown:               |Finally, the click that started it all is processed     |
+-------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this one out for myself. I feared I'd have to cobble together a threads-based solution, but a bit more docs-scouring turned up the `NSEvent` class method `addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler`.

When my app starts I call this method, define the associated block, and 'tell' the method what events I want to look out for. Then, whenever one of these events is detected, the block runs. Crucially ,this happens before any of the processing precipitated by the event is set in motion. In the block you have the opportunity to stop the event in its tracks, or let processing continue, you also have access to the event itself . Going back to my question, this means I am effectively inserting an additional row at the top of the table. This was perfect since it allows me to act on the event before any of the subsequent event executes.

```
[NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSLeftMouseDownMask 
                                      handler:^NSEvent *(NSEvent *event) {
    // whenever an event of type NSLeftMouseDownMask is detected, this code
    // will run before any other event processing

    // do some processing, then...

    return event; // or nil, if you want to block the event
}];
```